# What is the difference between an interface and an abstract class?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Interface vs Abstract Class (general OO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo)

I'm not exactly clear on the difference.

Thanks

Comment: there are a lot of posts on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761194/interface-vs-abstract-class-general-oo

Comment: ~Almond Joys have nuts, Mounds don't.~  Except replace "Almond Joys" with abstract classes, "Mounds" with interfaces, and "nuts" with some concrete methods.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

They are quite similar but there are some important technical differences:

- An abstract class allows you to provide a default implementation for some of the methods but an interface does not allow you to provide any implementations.
- You can implement multiple interfaces but you can only inherit from one abstract class.

These differences affect how the two techniques should be used:

- You should use an interface to *define a contract*.
- An abstract class can be useful to *reuse code*... but be aware that it is not the only way to reuse code. You should also consider other approaches such as containment.

Answer (score 4):

An interface doesn't allow definition of any of the member methods, whereas an abstract class does allow some or all to be defined. A class however can only extend one class (abstract or not) but can implement as many interfaces as it wants.

Answer (score 3):

I like to think of an interface as a contract.  any class that implements an interface, must provide details on what to do when any method defined in the contract is called.  An abstract class is a class that defined a set of actual behaviors, ie more than just a contract to be implemented later, but that class can't be instantiated.